# How can I end refreshing in another swift class?

Tags: swift, swift2, reachability, uirefreshcontrol

Hello im having this doubt can i end a refresh control in another class?
In my tableviewcontroller i have this:

```
func setRefreshGesture() {
let refreshGesture = UIRefreshControl()
refreshGesture.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
refreshGesture.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
refreshGesture.addTarget(WorkUpdater.sharedInstance,action:#selector(WorkUpdater.attemptUpdateControl),forControlEvents:.ValueChanged)      
self.refreshControl = refreshGesture
self.refreshControl?.layer.zPosition = self.tableView.backgroundView!.layer.zPosition + 1
    }
```

and in my other class.. have this:

```
 func attemptUpdateControl(){
        if !isUpdating && canPerformUpdate() {
            isUpdating = true
            performUpdateControl()
        } else {
            print("ERROR: - Update in progress")
        }
    }

 func performUpdateControl(){
        let reach = Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()!
        if reach.isReachable() {
        work.getData()
        } else {
            UIAlertView(title: "Device without connection", message: "You must have an internet connection to use this feature", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK").show()
```

//here i want to end my refresh of tableviewcontroller

}

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either setup custom `Delegate` or use `NSNotifcationCenter`. I am not sure what is your `TableViewController` relationship with `WorkUpdater`.

So I am showing you a possible way of doing it with `NSNotifactionCenter`. In your `TableViewController`, have this in `viewDidLoad`

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.refreshCompleted), name:"refreshCompleted", object: nil)
```

Then have a `refreshCompleted` func:

```
func refreshCompleted() {
    refreshGesture.endRefreshing()      //you have to set it as a class var
}
```

Also update the `WorkUpdater` with this:

```
func performUpdateControl(){
    let reach = Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()!
    if reach.isReachable() {
    work.getData()
    } else {
        UIAlertView(title: "Device without connection", message: "You must have an internet connection to use this feature", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK").show()
    }
    //add this        
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("refreshCompleted", object: nil)
}
```